# Is there a way to override methods, in c#, the way you can do in python?

Tags: python, c#, overriding

i'm starting to use c# for a unity game project I'm doing in uni, but i mainly use python to program so i was wondering:

is there a way to make an override of a method giving it a standard value if the relative parameter isn't passed?

Let's say i have a method that checks if an element is in a list (yes i know about the "in" keyword, it's an example):

```
def checkElementInList (element, list)
```

since i may or may not have the list when calling the method i would do this:

```
def checkElementInList (element, list = getList ())
```

so if i pass the list the program doesn't have to "make" it again but if i don't pass it the it `checkElementInList` calls the method to get the list.

Is there a way to do the same thing in c#? So instead of making an override of a method where the only difference is that i call the method to create the list at the beginning, i have one method where, if i pass the list it gets it from the input and if i don't it gets it from the method?

Comment: Yes Polymorphism exists in python and it does exist in C#

Comment: [yes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/member-overloading)

Comment: What you describe is an overload of a method in C#. Override is declaring a different version of an inherited method (virtual).

Answer (score 3):

Note that even in Python this might not do what you want: it's recommended that you avoid method calls like that in parameter default values. The reason is that `getList()` is called *once*, and the value returned is used thereafter. So if `checkElementInList` the modifies this list, that modification will be present in every default value for `list` after that.

You can have a parameter which has a default value of `null` in C#. In the body of your method, see whether it's null, and call `GetList()` if it is:

```
public override bool CheckElementInList(int element, List<int> list = null)
{
    list ??= GetList();
}
```

As noted above, this does differ slightly from your Python version: here, `GetList()` is called each time the uses doesn't pass the `list` parameter, whereas in the Python version `getList()` would be called once.

Comment: so i have to write 2 methods anyway(?)

Comment: @keepuru No? You can either write the two methods `CheckElementInList(int element, List<int> list)` and `CheckElementInList(int element)`, or you can use default parameter values to combine them into the single method `CheckElementInList(int element, List<int> list = null)`

Comment: I have tried a couple of times and i got it to work, thanks